# Is Sapper an old model replicant?

Tags: blade-runner-2049

When K talks to Sapper Morton, a former cyber-soldier now hiding from the authorities on a protein farm, [the following dialogue occurs](https://www.villagevoice.com/2017/09/29/blade-runner-2049-is-beautiful-but-does-it-have-that-old-blade-runner-magic/):

> **Sapper**: How does it feel, killing your own kind?
> **K**: I don’t retire my own kind because we don't run. Only old models run.
> **Sabber**: You new models. You’re happy scraping the shit. You’ve never seen a miracle.

Does this means that Sapper is an old model?
Does this means K is also a replicant?

Answer (score 2):

[Sapper Morton](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Sapper_Morton) is a Nexus **8** replicant (with an incept date of July 15, 2020), making him an older model, illegal to be on Earth.

[image]
<sub><sup>Image from [Blade Runner 2049: Blackout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrZk9sSgRyQ)</sup></sub>

[KD6-3.7](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/K), aka "K", is a Nexus 9 replicant assigned to the police force and tasked with tracking down and retiring any Nexus 8s who have made their way back from the colonies.

Comment: What does he means by “ don’t run”?

Comment: The Blade Runners go after Replicants that flee company control and try to hide among humans. K is saying his model doesn't rebel that way.